# SQL Server - Store accented characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to store and report out accented characters (i.e. ñ or í). The process is relatively simple. A text file is loaded via Bulk Insert and later extracted via Select statement.

Based on Googling, I think the details below might be useful:

- The database has a *SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS* collation
- The fields are NVARCHAR(200)
- When I run a Select, the results are:

  - ├▒ (instead of ñ)
  - ├¡ (instead of í)

How do I modify the database/table/column to hold the data?

I assumed this was a common question but Googling doesn't give me a clear answer or instructions. Some say NVARCHAR is enough. Other refer to **N'**, using Collate in the Select, adding the code page in the bulk insert, etc.

**Update:** I added a dbfiddle. I don't know how to execute a bulk insert in here so I'll just leave it commented out for now. Interestingly, the Insert() statements correctly transfer the data.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c3b8cdb9da9fddaef7a1e09b64194fb

Comment: Can you show the command you used to bulk insert, and describe the format/codepage of the file? When you run a select _where_? Can you provide a repro on [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle)? Seems to [work fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75667162567f98bc1d57e1835b193669) but I have zero clue how to manufacture the file you're bulk loading or the way you're doing it.

Comment: You 3 distinct parts to your problem, 1. ensuring your storage is setup to store these values, 2. ensuring you load the correct values and 3. ensuring you query the values correctly. You need to verify each of these stages.

Comment: whxynot simplxy use utf8 like the rest of the world

Comment: @DaleK that's correct and I can't find straightforward instructions on those 3 steps. I'm surprised it's not a more common question.

Comment: @nbk okay, how do I use utf8?

Comment: If you are using nvarchar for storage with the collation you specify, I would be suspicious of your bulk insert.

Comment: @DaleK I updated the post with a dbfiddle. The bulk insert is included.

Comment: @AaronBertrand added. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: For unicode you need to prefix constants with an N. Example: `VALUES(N'aañaa')`. If you do not do this it actually an ANSI value, not UNICODE. Change your inserts accordingly and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

For latin characters you don't even need nvarchar, just varchar is enough.

The codepage in your code on dbfiddle is not a codepage, but a collation.
Collations specify the way SQL Server is going to compare characters, and what you need is how SQL Server can translate the information from the file to the varchar. So you can try using UTF-8 codepage:

`CODEPAGE = '65001'`

Or RAW codepage, that's faster but sometimes can take the wrong conversion:

`CODEPAGE = 'RAW'`

Other values accepted on codepage are `OEM` and `ACP`, that is Windows default character.

My guess is that your file is using UTF-8, so give a try on 65001.